# Vlookup in filtered Range with Varaible Lookup Value, Variable Lookup Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply Vlookup on a filtered range with Variable Lookup Value(Changing according to the row number) and Variable Lookup Range(From a user browsed workbook). But, the formula bar after running the code shows the formula as :-

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(@Sri Lanka15-@a_One-@Time Base Rent,'[C_Rent Report_25082020.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$J$1:$N$968,4,0)," ")
```

I am not sure where these "@" signs are coming from. The lookup value for this particular row is :-Sri Lanka15-a_One-Time Base Rent.

Below is the code:-

```
    Dim LR As Long   ' Defined as Last row in source file
    Dim nlr As Long   'Defined as Last row in Macro Workbook where vlookup is applied
    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All Files(*.xls; *.xlsx; *.csv),*xls,*.xlsx, *csv", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Filename
    sourcefile = Dir(Filename)
    With ActiveSheet
       Range("A1:AQ" & nlr).AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:="One-Time Base Rent"
       For Each cell In Range("AA2:AA" & nlr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            lookupvalue = Cells(cell.Row, "Z").Value
            cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & lookupvalue & ",'[" & sourcefile & "]Sheet 1'!$J$1:$N$" & LR & ",4,0),"" "")"    ' The problem seems to be here in lookup value as rest are appearing as fine in formula
       Next
             
    End With
```

Since i need to apply subsequent filters after this. i would like to keep the lookup value as variable.

I have tried WorksheetFunction.Vlookup too, but i am not sure how to define the range from a file chosen by user in worksheetfunction

Any help is highly appreciated !!
Thanks

Comment: The file that you are opening, is it a csv file? To reference the file you have opened, declare a workbook variable (i.e. `Dim oWB as Workbook`). Then change your `Open` statement to something like: `Set oWB = Workbooks.Open Filename:=Filename`. Now you have access to everything in the file through `oWB` object

Comment: Aren't you missing a couple of inverted commas around lookupvalue in the formula?

Comment: @Zac :- I tried that way , but it gives a compile error and doesn't let me save the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try replacing of

```
cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & lookupvalue & ",'[" & sourcefile & "]Sheet 1'!$J$1:$N$" & LR & ",4,0),"" "")"
```

with

```
cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & cells(cell.Row, "Z").Address & ",'[" & sourceFile & "]Sheet 1'!$J$1:$N$" & lr & ",4,0),"" "")"
```

Comment: `cells(cell.Row, "Z").Address` can be simplified to `"Z" & cell.Row`...

Comment: @ BigBen: Of course. I only wanted to show, in the context of his code, that the cell address should be used instead of its value... :)

Comment: @Glad I could help! But take in consideration the above suggestion made by BigBen. It will simplify your code. And, of course, `lookupvalue` is not necessary, anymore...